# Django: TypeError: 'is_active' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

I keep receiving this error when I try to create a user via the createsuperuser management command:

TypeError: 'is_active' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

I have tried adding the is_active field, but to no avail. Also tried messing with the REQUIRED_FIELDS because the django docs say they must match the create_superuser fields. Still no luck.

Your guidance is much appreciated. Thanks! Here is the custom user model I am using:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
    """
    now = timezone.now()

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email,
                      is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                      is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                      date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    your_name   = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    company     = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    email       = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['your_name',]

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

**UPDATED** Omitted is_active = True from user = self.model. New error is: *TypeError: 'is_superuser' is an invalid keyword argument for this function*

Comment: how did you call to create superuser?

Comment: upon running syncdb for the first time, when it asks if you would like to create your first superuser: "You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now?"

Comment: What happens if you omit `is_active`?(for `AbstractBaseUser` it's `True` by default anyway).

Comment: Removed is_active = true from user = self.model. Now i get the error TypeError: 'is_superuser' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Don't forget the ```PermissionsMixin```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the exact same error, following Mike Hibbert's excellent advanced tutorial on defining a Custom User: http://www.mikesdjangotutorials.co.uk/  I was able to get it working by adding those fields to my CustomUser:

```
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

...I would have assumed they were inherited from AbstractBaseUser, but sure enough, they explain this clearly enough in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin  Note there are a few additional steps described there if you want your CustomUser to work in your Django Admin as well (starting with registering it, etc.)

Comment: I was also using Mike's excellent video tutorials! I eventually figured it out but forgot to post an update, so thanks for this. Cheers!

Comment: My problem was that I forgot the ```PermissionsMixin```

Answer (score 3):

You should remove every param that you not use in your model (`CustomUser`) init method and base classes init methods from that call:

```
user = self.model(email=email,
                  is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                  is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                  date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
```

You have derived `CustomUser` from `AbstractBaseUser` that not have init and derived from models.Model. That mean that you can pass to init only names of the fields you’ve defined on your model:

```
user = self.model(email=email, your_name=something, company=something)
```

Try to derive `CustomUser` from `AbstractUser`

Comment: I added the fields to CustomUser. Now I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state' Thanks for your help!

Comment: (this happens after I add the company). I added the company field to "REQUIRED_FIELDS" because i was getting an integrity error.

Comment: I set null = True, blank = True for company and removed it from REQUIRED_FIELDS. It works fine now, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: nevermind. now when I try to log into the admin i get 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'

Comment: i think you should review auth models in django source here contrib/auth/models.py. It is quite small and simple